# How do I add characters between each character in a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

If I have a string "hello", how would I add characters between each character in the string so it would look like "h--e--l--l--o"

Comment: @Sebastian, I do not doubt that this question is a dup but it not a dup of the question you referenced in closing the question. The earlier question would ask how `'hello'` could be converted to `'h-e-l-l-o-'`, not to `'h-e-l-l-o'`, a signficant different. I suggest it be reopened until a suitable dup reference is found.

Comment: Yess, I know there was a pretty similar question. If found we can update this and/or reopen it. Thanks @CarySwoveland.

Comment: @Sebastian, I voted to reopen and, voilà, it reopened. I thought several votes were need for that to happen (unless you reopened it). Reclose if you wish. Confused in Victoria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions to this, I would suggest the following :

1/ split the string into an `array` of individual characters with [`chars`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-chars)

```rb
"hello".chars
=> ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```

2/ [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-join) them with the two characters you want to add in-between each character

```rb
["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"].join('--')
=> "h--e--l--l--o"
```

You can execute this in one line as such :

```rb
"hello".chars.join('--')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that without converting the string to an array by using [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regular expression:

```
"hello".gsub(/(?<=.)(?=.)/, '--')
  #=> "h--e--l--l--o".
```

`(?<=.)` is a positive lookbehind, asserting that the match is preceded by a character and `(?=.)` is a positive lookahead, asserting that the match is followed by a character. Note that matches are zero-width; it is the locations between consecutive characters that are matched.